# Confused in uitableviewcell subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableViewController` I have two `custom cells` both are different `1st cell` contains a `UIButton` and `2nd cell` contains `UITextField`.

Currently I have only one `UITableViewCell subclass` which I am using for both cells.

- First cell only have button.
- Second cell only have text filed.

I want to know why I am not getting any error that cell1 have no textfield and vise versa.

Is this also a correct approach or I must give both cells different `subclass`.

Comment: Hi!, so you´ve something like this:

UITableViewController
   CustomCell
       UIButton
   CustomCell
       UITextField

Could you add the source code for CustomCell so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple custom cells in a TableView. In your delegate functions you will have decide on some criteria which cell you want to display and with what data.

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if([this cell should be of type 1])
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCellType1];

    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCellType2];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

If you want to keep only one custom class type, keep both button and text element in the cell and just hide and unhide based on the current cell's index.

Comment: thanks for replying but please read my question one more time, I wanna know am I doing correct by giving two different custom cell a same subclass.

Comment: you could keep both in button and textfield in one.. but then you would have to hide and unhide either one based on the cell. i will update the answer.. you could also create 2 cells types

Comment: but I am having no issue so why should I hide or unhide, I wanna know logically am I doing right or wrong?

Comment: logically you should define 2 diff cells.